# Unable to Fill Background of Rectanle using Html Canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am trying to fill the rectangle that i have drawn onto a canvas using Javascript. However when i try with the below code my rectangle doesn't even render at all with no error messages i am unsure what i have done wrong. suggestions?

```
  ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(150, 0, 3, 75);
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = window.location.host + "/wp-content/plugins/productdesigner/assets/Cords/T-911 Neon Orange.jpg";
    img.onload = function() {
      var pattern = ctx.createPattern(this,"repeat");
      ctx.fillStyle = pattern;
      ctx.fill();
    };
  ctx.closePath();
```

Comment: Your code isn't complete. Add all of your code or create demo.

Comment: See https://jsfiddle.net/3dk4447k/

Comment: @Mohammad your code looks good but for some reason doesnt render on my code?

Comment: Check that `img.src` is right.

Comment: that being said i just used the inital src to test it but that didnt show up either? like on the jsfiddle

Comment: Test url of image in browser and see result. Probably image address is wrong.

Comment: I have checked and verified that the img.src does work in the browser.

Comment: I meaning check `window.location.host + "/wp-content/plugins/productdesigner/assets/Cords/T-911 Neon Orange.jpg` exist and is an image.

Comment: @Mohammad i found out using console.log that the onload function does not fire?

Comment: If image address be wrong, `onload` event doesn't fired. Change address of image and test it.

Comment: Omg you right I didn't realise I was using the wrong window.location

Comment: @Mohammad okay so I fixed the url and the function fires correctly and the image loads using browser url. Still doesn't render the rectangle with the pattern :/

Comment: I think I have done it wrong because the pattern is on the wrong shape thanks for the help